# Is possible to return a S3Object from Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, amazon-s3

I'm quite noob with REST APIs and Spring Boot in particular. I'm coding a microservice which is asked for S3 files and must somehow return them. Files will be too big (2GB+) to keep in the microservice memory and then send it back to the caller, so I thought I could simply return a serialized S3Object, and my clients could stream the file contents, with chunks, via repeated calls to S3ObjectInputStream.read(bytes[]).

I'm having a hard time making this possible, and due to my limited knowledge I don't even thing if this is possible or if I'm thinking wright.

I've tried returning a ResponseEntity. With Postman everything is cool, and S3Object is serialized correctly with jackson library, but deseralization at the client side crashes because method S3Object.setObjectContent is overloaded and multiple setters conflict.

Returning a ResponseEntity with SerializationUtils.serialize(S3Object) as body fails too. Even S3Object implementing Serializable interface, every time, the byte[] resulting is of length 1000, and when I deserialize, I can't get the object contents because S3Object.getObjectContent() always return null.

What can I do?

Comment: Can't you create a signed download url and redirect to it? Letting the user download it from S3 directly instead of via your server?

Answer (score 0):

No need for that, I don't think. Here's an example of how to return a requested file using a RESTful api:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/downloads/{fileName}",
    method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS},
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void downloadPolicyDocument( 
    @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Range");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Accept-Ranges, Content-Encoding, Content-Length, Content-Range");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + id + "\"");

    try (InputStream inputStream = yourMethodThatGetsTheFileAsBufferedInputStream(fileName)) {

        ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
        WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentLength(fastChannelCopy(inputChannel, outputChannel));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new YourCustom404Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Add other MediaType to the "produces" attribute that you expect to be downloaded from this endpoint, or add another similar endpoint for each mediatype.